# Where should “efficiently” go? “…to use ___ the money we collected ___.”

Tags: grammar, verbs, adverbs, grammaticality-in-context

I need to answer a business-related e-mail. The intended thing is using the money efficiently.

According to some sources are expressed as follows:" to use technology wisely ". Which one is correct grammatically?

1. We request your approval to use efficiently the money we collected.
2. We request your approval to use the money we collected efficiently.
3. We request your approval to use the money efficiently we collected.

Comment: The "use" is efficient or the "collecting"? What do you want to say? Maybe you explain the context is a few words?

Comment: The "use" is efficient. It's necessary is using money efficiently.

Comment: I just realized something after answering: you ask approval for actually using the money (knowing that they will be used efficiently), or you ask approval for efficiency, knowing that the money will be used anyway?

Comment: The money will be used in all cases. We want to use it "efficiently" with this approval.

Comment: You want to say that if you do **not** have approval, you will spend the money inefficiently? (sounds like retaliation, revenge: If you do not approve efficiency, we shall waste the money!)

Comment: The approval I mentioned, like permission or allow.

Comment: I understood about "approval". I wanted to ask: **What will you do if you do NOT get approval?** Not spend the money at all? Or spend the money, but inefficiently? Or maybe even ignore the answer, you will spend money efficiently anyway?

Comment: We'il use the money somehow. Why not use it more efficiently, our goal is to close the debt more. Therefore we ask for approval.

Comment: According to some sources are expressed as follows:" to use technology wisely ". In such a case, can we use the verb in front of the adverb? For example: "We request your approval to use the money efficiently we collected."

Comment: Are you approving the use of the money, and requesting that those spending it do so efficiently?  Or are you the one asking for approval, and are promising to use it efficiently?  Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

**"the collected money"** is much better than **"the money we collected"**

Thus I would recommend this:

> 1. We request your approval to efficiently use the collected money.

I favor this less:

> 1. We request your approval to use the collected money efficiently.

"Efficiently" is mostly redundant:

> 1. We request your approval to use the collected money.

Or (maybe) even better:

> We request your approval to use the collected money. It will be used efficiently ...*(describe shortly how it will be used efficiently)*.

Good observation from **@RubioRic** (thank you):

> Being "money" an uncountable noun, I think that it should be: **"it will be used..."** instead of **"they will be..."**

Comment: Being "money" an uncountable noun, I think that it should be "it will be used..." instead of "they will be..